# atomic representation of a sentence for noun initialization

Tags: j

In a data structure such as

[image]

I want to be able to use  ". (do) to initialize what could be a long list of noun names on the left with the values on the right in a nested array. A value could be a nested array.   5!:5 requires a noun name to get the atomic representation. What is the approach to get the AR of just the data such as a nested array such as <'data';'data';100?

Comment: Multiple assignment only requires atomic reps in the case that such values must be evoked (ie turned from a gerund to a non-noun pert of speech). This is only the case for non-nouns, and when you, the programmer, triggers the evocation by starting the literal to the left of the copula with a `\``. For nouns, as you have it here, you can use regular old indirect assignment: `'IsArchived IsListed IsPrivate IsDeleted IsLocked' =: 0 0 1 1 0 `.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the AR of a noun I use this:

```
   5!:1 <'t' [ t=. <'data';'data';100
┌─────────────────────┐
│┌─┬─────────────────┐│
││0│┌───────────────┐││
││ ││┌────┬────┬───┐│││
││ │││data│data│100││││
││ ││└────┴────┴───┘│││
││ │└───────────────┘││
│└─┴─────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────┘
```

if you wanted to extend it to other parts of speech that you had stored as a linear text expression, you could do this:

```
   5!:1 <'t' [ ". 't=.', '<''data'';''data'';100'
┌─────────────────────┐
│┌─┬─────────────────┐│
││0│┌───────────────┐││
││ ││┌────┬────┬───┐│││
││ │││data│data│100││││
││ ││└────┴────┴───┘│││
││ │└───────────────┘││
│└─┴─────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────┘
```

which requires the extra qoutes within a quote but allows all parts of speech if they are in text format:

```
   5!:1 <'t' [ ". 't=.', '+'
┌─┐
│+│
└─┘
```

But if you have the structure that you indicate, why not do something like this:

```
   [ s=:4 3 $ 'one';'=:';1;'two';'=:';2;'three';'=:';3;'four';'=:';4
┌─────┬──┬─┐
│one  │=:│1│
├─────┼──┼─┤
│two  │=:│2│
├─────┼──┼─┤
│three│=:│3│
├─────┼──┼─┤
│four │=:│4│
└─────┴──┴─┘
   {:"1 s
┌─┬─┬─┬─┐
│1│2│3│4│
└─┴─┴─┴─┘
   (;:^:_1 {."1 s)
one two three four
   (;:^:_1 {."1 s)=.{:"1 s
   one
1
   two
2
   three
3
   four
4
```

ADDED SOLUTION

Since you only want nouns to be represented as an AR, you can always just construct them according to the rules of an AR. Box the noun, append the list '0' and then box that result.

```
   arc =: 3 : '5!:1 < ''y''' NB. explict verb to create AR using intermediate name
   ar=. < @:((<, '0'),<)     NB. tacit verb to construct AR for nouns with no intermediate name
   (arc -: ar) 5
1
   (arc -: ar) <'data';'data';100
1
   (arc -: ar) 5;<'data';3j2
1
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the AR of that boxed data without "naming" it first? That AR would be appended to "=:" and that to the noun name then executed with "do".  The goal is to initialize a large number of global variables with boxed data in addition to just integer data as shown in the image. Put another way, how would you assign boxed data in the third column to names in the first? I could just put it all in a script but then initializing many nouns with different values isn't "automated" via ". .

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, you could use `5!:0` , which is an adverb that converts AR's back to the values. and then do the assignment. The only way I know of to get an AR is to use that intermediate name trick. The second part of your question I think I have answered with `(;:^:_1 {."1 s) =. {:"1 s` as that middle =. is acting as the assignment between the left `(;:^:_1 {."1 s)` and the right `{:"1 s`

Comment: I will work in the intermediate name approach but wanted to make sure there was no way to AR an unnamed data structure. The intent was to create a useful display of large numbers of nouns used in a database along with sample or initial cell data. The topper would be to use the same nested display array to also simply assign the data displayed to the name nouns as needed.

Comment: Related is how to edit the maximum display length of the J Term to allow displaying a boxed array like shown perhaps with 300 rows without truncation.

Comment: 9!:36 to find the display constraints and 9!:37 to change them are the foreign conjunctions that I think that you will want to look at for that.

Comment: See added solution for the case where all of your contents are nouns and you want an AR for those nouns, if that is what you are looking for?